# Python LDAP3 invalid class in objectClass attribute: group

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

First of all, the documentation and examples are so bad, please explain for simple people, like me. Rant over.

I am trying to access my organizations ldap server. Ive tried python-ldap, but i ran into issues, where it decodes and encodes responses super weird. I am testing ldap3 lib atm. But i cannot use the same stuff using ldap3.

```
def ldap3_connection_initalizer(username, password):
    server = ldap3.Server('ldap.blaah.blaaah')
    connection = ldap3.Connection(server, user=f'uid={username},ou=people,ou=users,dc=blaah,dc=blaah', password=f'{password}')
    with ldap3.Connection(server, user=f'uid={username},ou=people,ou=users,dc=blaah,dc=blaaah', password=f'{password}', auto_bind = True) as c:
        print(c)
        base_dn='ou=people,ou=users,dc=blaaah,dc=blaaah'
        status, result, response, _ = c.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter='(objectClass=group)', search_scope='SUBTREE', attributes = ['member'])

        print(status)
        print(result)
        print(response)
```

Running this I get : ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPObjectClassError: invalid class in objectClass attribute: group

and before that     raise LDAPObjectClassError('invalid class in objectClass attribute: ' + str(value))

Could anyone explain why is this not working, but examples in the internet use similar response and it works?

EDIT: Update, tried to change group to person and got this error TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Answer (score 1):

The 1st error says that `group` is not a valid objectClass (actually it exists but is specific to some Active Directory groups - AD only), so you need to fix the filter. The most generic objectClass for structuring a group entry (ie. having *member* attribute) is `groupOfNames` (cf. [LDAP Group](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Group)).

Then you changed the filter with `(objectClass=person)` which is valid (but for user entries), so you run into the 2nd error which is related to how is unpacked the returned value(s) from `c.search()`.  By default ldap3' search() function returns only the status (other values are returned only when the "strategy" is defined to be thread-safe, which is not obvious at all).

When running a search the response is always added to the connection object via the `response` keyword, so in order to get the actual ldap entries whatever the thread mode, we can just iterate the connection response.

To sum it up, you can do :

```
status = c.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter='(objectClass=groupOfNames)', search_scope='SUBTREE', attributes = ['member'])
print(status)
for entry in c.response:
    print(entry['dn'])
    print(entry['attributes'])
```